# What’s the penalty if I enable `track_commit_timestamp`?

Tags: postgresql, configuration

I just learned about PostgreSQL’s `xmin` system column, `pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xid)` function and `track_commit_timestamp` option.

I’m considering enabling this option on my PostgreSQL databases, as a help for investigation if something strange happens in the data.

But I see that this option is disabled by default and my *guess* is that it is so because that option may have a significant penalty.

Hence, what penalty should I expect if I enable this option?

Comment: I don't think the performance penalty will be terrible. Benchmark it!